# DOS Batch FOR Loop to delete Files not Containing a String

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I want to delete all the files in the current directory which do not contain the string "sample" in their name.

for instance,

```
test_final_1.exe
test_initial_1.exe
test_sample_1.exe
test_sample_2.exe
```

I want to delete all the files other than the ones containing *sample* in their name.

```
for %i in (*.*) do if not %i == "*sample*" del /f /q %i

Is the use of wild card character in the if condition allowed?
Does, (*.*) represent the current directory?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest to use FIND or FINDSTR with `/V` option to look for names that don't contain a string, and `/I` option for case insenstive search. Switch to `FOR /F` and pipe results of `DIR` to `FIND`.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d * ^| find /v /i "sample"') do del "%F"
```

change %F to %%F if used in a batch file.

Comment: Thanks. That works. It even works without adding, "eol=: delims=". May I know what is the reason for using it in the above command line? Also, the additional arguments to the dir command other than /b. I understand the use of /b switch however, what is the use of /a-d?

Comment: Use `HELP DIR` from the command line for help on all the options. But `/a-d` excludes folders from the output. `DELIMS` should be set to nothing to preserve the entire file name. The default of space and tab would break at the first space in a file name. A `;` is a valid file name character. Any file name starting with `;` would be ignored by `FOR` with the default `EOL` option. No file name can contain a `:`, so I set the `EOL` option to that character.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Aacini worked for me.  I needed a bat file to parse the directory tree finding all files with xyz file extension and not containing badvalue anywhere in the path.  The solution was:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /r %%f in (*.xyz) do (
   set "str1=%%f"
   if "!str1!" == "!str1:badvalue=!" (
        echo Found file with xyz extension and without badvalue in path
   )
)
```

Comment: This isn't really different from Aacini's answer. What does it add?

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %i in (*.*) do (set "name=%i" & if "!name!" == "!name:sample=!" del /f /q %i)
```